# What diff between Total CPU Usage and Process CPU Usage

Tags: linux, top

When I using `top` command often find that Single process CPU Usage is very High But Total CPU Usage is lower.

Comment: Is this on a multicore system? For example, one single threaded process might be 100%, but on a 4 core system, the overall CPU would be 25%.

Comment: Wether One process just Only Using one core?